# Вставка текста в поле textarea посредством JS

Tags: javascript

Есть  поле `<textarea name="text"></textarea>`. Подскажите самую простую реализацию кнопки/псевдокнопки, при нажатии на которую в поле будет вставляться определенный текст без перезагрузки страницы.
В JS я очень слаб.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простейший способ:

```
<button onclick='document.querySelector("textarea[name=text]").value="Текст, который необходимо вставить"'>Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можно сделать, чтобы при этом не стирался весь остальной текст, который уже написан в textarea?

Comment: Разумеется, достаточно заменить здесь знак `=` на `+=`

Comment: И совсем последняя просьба. Можно ли добавлять текст не в самый конец, а туда, где находится курсор? Или это значительно усложнит реализацию?

Comment: Ну это точно не в одну строчку, и достойно отдельного вопроса